# Partition a column based on keywords in Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file that I have read into python as a dataframe as shown.

```
   Store       List
   Ralphs      bag1   
               apple
               pear
   Ralphs      bag2
               toilet paper 
   Albertsons  bag3
               magazines
               paper
```

I am attempting to expand the second column into two columns as shown.

```
   Bag       Item
   bag1      Apple
   bag1      Pear
   bag2      Toilet Paper       
   bag3      Magazines
   bag3      paper
```

The store column has Na's whenever an item is listed in the original table. Is there some pandas function that has a seperate function based on the Na's? or would it be easier to create a Series with all the bags and use that as some cutting point?

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
df
        Store          List
0      Ralphs          bag1
1      Ralphs         apple
2      Ralphs          pear
3      Ralphs          bag2
4      Ralphs  toilet paper
5  Albertsons          bag3
6  Albertsons     magazines
7  Albertsons         paper
```

---

You can use `df.where` with `str.contains`, extracting all rows which start with `bag`, and then filter out spurious rows.

```
df = df.assign(Bag=df.List.\
       where(df.List.str.contains('bag')).ffill()).drop('Store', 1)
df[df.List != df.Bag]

           List   Bag
1         apple  bag1
2          pear  bag1
4  toilet paper  bag2
6     magazines  bag3
7         paper  bag3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column that assign to each item its bag then groupby `bag id` as follows:

```
df['bag'] = "bag"+df.List.str.contains('bag').cumsum().astype(str)    
df[['bag','List']].groupby('bag').apply(lambda x: x[1:]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

or, instead of `groupby`, filter out the elements where `df.List == df.bag` (which will be `bag1 == bag1`, `bag2 == bag2` .. )

```
df['bag'] = "bag"+df.List.str.contains('bag').cumsum().astype(str)    
df[df.List != df.bag].drop('Store', axis=1)
```

---

Overall execution

```
In [83]: df
Out[83]: 
        Store          List
0      Ralphs          bag1
1         NaN         apple
2         NaN          pear
3      Ralphs          bag2
4         NaN  toilet paper
5  Albertsons          bag3
6         NaN     magazines
7         Nan         paper

In [84]: df['bag'] = "bag"+df.List.str.contains('bag').cumsum().astype(str)

In [85]: df[['bag','List']].groupby('bag').apply(lambda x: x[1:]).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[85]: 
    bag          List
0  bag1         apple
1  bag1          pear
2  bag2  toilet paper
3  bag3     magazines
4  bag3         paper
```